# Scrolling marquee not showing content

Tags: html, css, marquee

This marquee at the bottom of the page works fine on a page of its own with just the marquee but on this page im in the process of creating something is affecting it showing its content.

Any ideas guys? Its css is completely the same as on the other page.
Tried changing visibility to visible but then after it scrolls to the top of the marquee it starts again when there are more images to come.
http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm

Comment: not really getting the question here, but get rid of marquee altogether, try looking into javascript / jquery alternatives... one example [http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)

Comment: ...and here are the details why you should not use marquee (have a look at the top with red background "Non-standard"): [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: ok i see. is there a simpler option than that jquery one? ive never touched it before, looks complicatec

Comment: it's best to comply, otherwise your code will be outdated and some of your audience would not be able to enjoy your coding masterpiece ;) jquery is a very useful one to learn!

Comment: what about this. the guy says marquee done full circles and ended up here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

Comment: good luck with that! ;)

Comment: dont get your panties in a knot mate. the marquee works for now and im going to continue to use it until i find a replacement i can understand. for now i just need to figure out why the content isnt showing

Comment: i'm totally cool... mate ;)

Comment: what about this one? http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-news-ticker